# When do the various enemy types show up?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Through some research (such as [How does enemy progression work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87524/how-does-enemy-progression-work)) I have gotten the vague idea that harder enemy types show up based on how much time has elapsed in your game.

Are exact, or even nearly-exact values for the various unit types known?

For example, do Mutons reliably start showing up after 60 days have passed? Etc.

Comment: Note that the second answer is the correct one on that question.  Aliens show up in specific months, and the main alien on the UFO changes based on where in the story you are.  To avoid your question being a duplicate, are you asking about the expansion?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was provided as an answer for the question linked in my original post. I have copied Hubba88's answer and Zommuter's comment here for consistency.

---

**March**: Sectoids, Thin Men, Outsiders

**April**: Floaters, Chrysalids

**May**: Mutons

**June**: Cyberdiscs, Heavy Floaters

**July**: Muton Berserkers

---

**Alien Base**: Drones, Sectoid Commanders

**Overseer**: Muton Elite, Sectopods, Ethereals

---

**Slingshot DLC Mission 1**: Thin Men, Chrysalids

**Slingshot DLC Mission 2**: Mutons

**Slingshot DLC Mission 3**: Cyberdiscs

Comment: this is true for eu, but im not sure its identical for ew. also, you don't even onclude the new aliens!

Comment: hmm I could be wrong, in my latest game despite me intentionally delaying overseer I haven't ran into a sectopod yet.